# JSON File Creation using for each loop And Map - It repeats the first element value on all iterations over for loop

Tags: java, json, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

For each loop below not adding all 6 values from the list. Instead It just repeats the first value 6times. Also Json file created with the same inputs.

Note: I also referred to this link but not getting the expected output. [Javascript each loop over JSON only getting first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664190/javascript-each-loop-over-json-only-getting-first-element)

Steps followed are,
    1. Find the tr elements and read data one by one
    2. While reading store these values also using Map 
    3. Add the map values into Jason Array.

Below is my code,

```
public static void GetPercentageValue(String locatorType, String locatorValue) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    locatorType="xpath";
    locatorValue="//div[@class='content shadow']/div/child::table[1]/tbody/tr";
    List<WebElement>  tableRows=findTheElements(locatorType,locatorValue);
    for(WebElement tablerow : tableRows)
    {
        Map map = new LinkedHashMap(tableRows.size());
        row=row+1;
        String rowKeys=tablerow.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content shadow']/div/child::table[1]/tbody/tr['"+row+"']/td[1]")).getText();
        String price=tablerow.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content shadow']/div/child::table[1]/tbody/tr['"+row+"']//input")).getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("RowDesc & Price: "+rowKeys+" "+price);
        map.put(rowKeys, price);
        jArr.add(map);
    }
    jaObj.put("Values", jArr);
     PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(mbsDataPath1);
     pWriter.write(jaObj.toJSONString());
     pWriter.flush();
     pWriter.close();
}
```

Expected Output should be:

```
RowDesc & Price: <80.000            0
RowDesc & Price: 80.000-150.000     2
RowDesc & Price: 150.000-300.000    10
RowDesc & Price: 300.000-500.000    15
RowDesc & Price: >500.000           18
```

Actual Output of the above code is:

```
RowDesc & Price: <80.000 0
RowDesc & Price: <80.000 0
RowDesc & Price: <80.000 0
RowDesc & Price: <80.000 0
RowDesc & Price: <80.000 0
```

Comment: I cannot see initialization of "row"

Comment: could I take a look at your HTML input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple. You have incorrect XPATH

```
String rowKeys=tablerow.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content shadow']/div/child::table[1]/tbody/tr['"+row+"']/td[1]")).getText();
String price=tablerow.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content shadow']/div/child::table[1]/tbody/tr['"+row+"']//input")).getAttribute("value");
```

How you pass `row` variable is crucial!

You pass it as a String (in context of Xpath), instead of a digit.

Let's assume that `row=1`

Your Xpath looks like this:

```
String rowKeys=tablerow.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content shadow']/div/child::table[1]/tbody/tr['1']/td[1]")).getText();
```

Do you see it now? You create `tr['1']` instead of `tr[1]` and YES - it does matter.
If you pass it as `tr['1']` then you will match ALL of `tr` elements, instead of a specific index. It causes Selenium to match always the first element from the list of all `tr`s!

Just change your Xpaths to:

```
String rowKeys=tablerow.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content shadow']/div/child::table[1]/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td[1]")).getText();
String price=tablerow.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content shadow']/div/child::table[1]/tbody/tr["+row+"]//input")).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Thats interesting. It worked now after this correction. I learned from here is when passing an int value we need to remove the single quotes. Thanks again.